# Sub-Total didn't calculate in Shipping Order

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In MVC Razor when I calculated `Sub-Total` equals `ListPrice * Quantity`. I got this problem

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

```
<td>
    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CartItems[ix].Product.ListPrice * m.CartItems[ix].Quantity)
</td>
```

The problem is solved by me, thanks for your attention!

**EDIT**:

```
<td>
      @{
         var calculated = Model.CartItems[ix].Product.ListPrice * Model.CartItems[ix].Quantity;
                }
        <div class="price">@calculated</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use TextBoxFor for a calculated result, use Label instead.

Update your code like this;

```
<td>
    Html.Label(m => m.CartItems[ix].Product.ListPrice * m.CartItems[ix].Quantity)
</td>
```

Or create a property in your CartItem object

```
public decimal Calculated
{
    get { return Product.ListPrice * Quantity; }
}
```

Then use this property in on the razor page;

```
<td>
    Html.Label(m => m.CartItems[ix].Calculated)
</td>
```

Comment: I very appreciate your effort but it still didn't work, man! :)

Comment: You can see my answer that I just updated @Serkan Holat!

Comment: @TrungPham Well, that looks logical :) Probably I'm making a syntax mistake. Additionally, you can add this "Calculated" property to your CartItem object. I've updated my answer, in case you wonder.